# Saving And Retrieving In Dicom Files With ClearCanvas?

Tags: dicom, clearcanvas

Now I'm developing a small project concerned with medical imaging. I'm using C#.net 2008 and clearcanvas for saving and retrieving dicom files. I want to ask some questions about clearcanvas.

For saving, sometimes it is saved with XML file, sometimes not. Does this have any effect in retrieving?

Another one is when I'm saving single frame dicom files. It's OK, but for multiple frame dicom files (larger size), it an error occurs like this Unexpected network error:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'
```

Is getting thrown. Sometimes I get this message:

```
"Timeout waiting for response message, continuing.(Error) Unexpected association 
abort received from imgserver".
```

The last one is how I retrieve those files. I know it saved with issuedate\instanceUID,but, I don't know how to implement it. Please help me my friends,i really need it.

Comment: Showing your code using the clear canvas library might help get answers.

Answer (score 0):

A number of ClearCanvas applications use XML files (they're called Study XML files) to save a summary of the DICOM tags within all the DICOM Series and Instances within the Study.  This gives the ClearCanvas applications quick access to the contents of the study.  It sounds like you're writing your own Client application using the DICOM assemblies.  Unless you had a similar need due to the design of your application, you shouldn't have to generate the XML files in your application.

As for your errors with multi-frame DICOM files and receiving both timeout and out of memory errors, do you know how large these files are and how much available memory you have on our test system?  ClearCanvas requires that the entire image received be stored in memory before saving to disk.  This would also require a contiguous chunk of memory for the pixel data.  In the end, you need a significant amount of memory to use the ClearCanvas DICOM libraries with multi-frame images.

Answer (score 0):

> "Timeout waiting for response message, continuing.(Error) Unexpected association 
>   abort received from imgserver".

Look at the clear canvas logs and the logs of the DICOM service provider you are communicating with.  The provider logs should spell out why an abort was sent.